# how to open IE in private mode using selenium web drive for C#

Tags: c#, selenium, internet-explorer

I was trying to use the following code and run the tests in private mode of Internet Explorer but an error occurred when trying to launch the browser.

**Code**

```
InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions()
    {
        ForceCreateProcessApi = true,
        BrowserCommandLineArguments = "-private",
    };
   IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
```

**Error exception**

> Exception:    OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException:
>   OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: Unexpected error launching
>   Internet Explorer. Unable to use CreateProcess() API. To use
>   CreateProcess() with Internet Explorer 8 or higher, the value of
>   registry setting in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet
>   Explorer\Main\TabProcGrowth must be '0'.....

Even after removing the line ForceCreateProcessApi = true, it is not opening in private browser

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.FORCE_CREATE_PROCESS, true); 
capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_SWITCHES, "-private");
```

Comment: DesiredCapabilities has been made obsolete: *Use of DesiredCapabilities has been deprecated in favor of browser-specific Options classes*

Answer (score 0):

Please consider this article https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver you need to add mentioned registry value